# SSAS multiple dimensions name

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I have Fact table with multiple association with one dimension.

```
fact
    - someMeasure
    - CityFromID
    - CityToID

dimension
    - CityID
    - CityName
```

I would like to have different "friendly" name for CitiName based on particular ID from fact.
In this example, "City from" and "City to".

Only way I find, is create multiple dimensions based on the same datasource table and create translation as required. But this is quite hard to maintain.

Is there a better way?

Thank you.

**EDIT**: picture for clarify:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the FriendlyName of CityFromID to "City from" and CityToID to "City to"?
You later define what this relationship actually shows as data (in your case that would probably be CityName). Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have added picture to clarify my question. I can't find where can be defined FriendlyName in cube.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. You are using the cube Browser, yes? What if you go to Cube structure tab and then click on the dimension City From. After you click that, you have to open the properties (F4). With the dimension selected, you can change the "Name" attribute. Currently it is probably named "City Name" in both dimensions. Just change the name in each of the dimensions and I guess you're set.